# Problems with plotting using NDSolveValue

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have solved, using NDSolveValue a PDE. I now want to create a plot of my function u[x,t] and evaluate this function at  x = 1 and t = 1/4 and x = [Pi]/2, and  t = 1/2.

Im not sure how to extract the function and plot it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far ...

[image]

Comment: Post the code instead of screenshot

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1921324).

Answer (score 0):

```
{{"x", "y", "s[x,t]"}, {1, 1/4, s[1, 1/4]}, {\[Pi]/2, 1/2, 
   s[\[Pi]/2, 1/2]}} // TableForm
```

[image]